# Removing cases in a long dataframe

Tags: r

I am currently experiencing a problem where I have a long dataframe (i.e., multiple rows per subject) and want to remove cases that don't have any measurements (in any of the rows) on one variable. I've tried transforming the data to wide format, but this was a problem as I can't go back anymore (going from long to wide "destroys" my timeline variable). Does anyone have an idea about how to fix this problem?

Below is some code to simulate the head of my data. Specifically, I want to remove cases that don't have a measurement of extraversion on any of the measurement occasions ("time").

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), time = c(79L, 95L, 79L, 28L, 40L, 52L), 
extraversion = c(3.2, NA, NA, 2, 2.4, NA), satisfaction = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 9L), 
`self-esteem` = c(4.9, NA, NA, 6.9, 6.7, NA)), .Names = c("id", "time", "extraversion", 
"satisfaction", "self-esteem"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Note: I realise the missing of my extraversion variable coincides with my self-esteem variable.

Comment: So only id==2 should be dropped, correct?

Comment: In this small snippet of data, yes. However, I also have cases that have multiple lines of data, but do not have any measurements on extraversion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop an entire `id` if they don't have any measurements for `extraversion` you could do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, drop := all(is.na(extraversion)) ,by= id][!df$drop]

#   id time extraversion satisfaction self-esteem  drop
#1:  1   79          3.2            3         4.9 FALSE
#2:  1   95           NA            3          NA FALSE
#3:  3   28          2.0            5         6.9 FALSE
#4:  3   40          2.4            5         6.7 FALSE
#5:  3   52           NA            9          NA FALSE
```

Or you could use `.I` which I believe should be faster:

```
setDT(df)[df[,.I[!all(is.na(extraversion))], by = id]$V1]
```

---

Lastly, a base R solution could use `ave` (thanks to @thelatemail for the suggestion to make it shorter/more expressive):

```
df[!ave(is.na(df$extraversion), df$id, FUN = all),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data frame is named `mydata`, use a `dplyr` filter:

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(!all(is.na(extraversion))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
      time = c(79L, 95L, 79L, 28L, 40L, 52L),
      extraversion = c(3.2, NA, NA, 2, 2.4, NA),
      satisfaction = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 9L),
      `self-esteem` = c(4.9, NA, NA, 6.9, 6.7, NA)
    ),
    .Names = c("id", "time", "extraversion",
               "satisfaction", "self-esteem"),
    row.names = c(NA, 6L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

d[complete.cases(d$extraversion), ]

d[is.na(d$extraversion), ]
```

complete.cases is great if you wanted to remove any rows with missing data: complete.cases(d)